# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method log()

Tags: magento2, product, fatal-error, log

[image: click on add product throwing error]

when i click on Add product, i get the above error in the pic. Can anyone please help me on this how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of the custom module, maybe you are missing luzern/conotification module. 
Check this module is enabled or not by this:

```
php bin/magento module:status Luzern_Conotification
```

I hope this will help you what your issue is

Regards